# truncating a pandas multindex at a given level

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas multi-index like so

```
                          var_0  var_1
    instances timepoints              
    0         1               1      4
              2               2      5
              3               3      6
              4               5      8
    1         1               1      4
              2               2     55
              3               3      6
              4               3      6
    2         1               1     42
              2               2      5
              3               3      6
```

How do I truncate it so for every instance I only have the first n timepoints? eg.2

```
                            var_0  var_1
    instances timepoints              
     0         1               1      4
               2               2      5
     1         1               1      4
               2               2      55
     2         1               1      42
               2               2      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `multi-index df` is `df`

```
df_new = df.groupby(level=0).head(2)
print(df_new)
```

#Haven't tested...it should work..pls, Let me knwo if it doesn't work

Comment: Tested and works perfectly in my case, Can you tell me why its level 0 and not one please ?

Comment: Grouby for `Multi index`  level must not have any duplicates ..if the duplicate rows are valid, then what sets them apart from each other..In past I've tried this...it throwed some `exception` like ...raise Exception('level has duplicate keys)...Not sure anyway Just written the answer based on my previouse instance...i once solved similar `Multi-Index` df